# Cut off program after printing specified number of lines to stdout

Tags: bash, ubuntu, stdout

I would like to execute program that prints to `stdout`:

```
drubbels@drubbels:~$ ./foobar
 Welcome to foobar!
 This program prints a bunch of output
 and then a bunch more
 and then it's done
drubbels@drubbels:~$
```

...but automatically cut it off after a specific number of lines. Something a little like this:

```
drubbels@drubbels:~$ limit-after-lines -numlines=2 ./foobar
 Welcome to foobar!
 This program prints a bunch of output
drubbels@drubbels:~$
```

Or perhaps like this:

```
drubbels@drubbels:~$ ./foobar > /dev/limit-after-lines -numlines=2
 Welcome to foobar!
 This program prints a bunch of output
drubbels@drubbels:~$
```

Note: I'm not looking to *only* cut off the output (I suppose that could be accomplished with `head`) - I'm specifically looking to halt the execution of the program after a given number of lines (or perhaps more generally, after `stdout` matches some given regular expression).

Comment: `./foobar | head -n 2`; similarly `./foobar | sed '/regex/q'`

Comment: foobar will stop when the pipe is closed by `head` and it gets SIGPIPE